# puppeteer запретить загрузку файлов

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

я ищу через кукольник информацию в гугл, часть поисковой выдачи - это ссылки на файлы документов, которые скачиваются, я их не обрабатываю и они просто занимают место. Как можно запретить скачивание файлов? я пробовал это:

```
page.on('response', async response =>
    {
        if(response.headers()['content-type'].indexOf('text/html') === -1)
            {
                response.abort();
            }
    });
```

в условие попадаю, но файл всё равно скачивается. Я могу по расширению перед переходом на страницу проверить, но хотелось бы более универсальный вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [`Page.setDownloadBehavior`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-setDownloadBehavior) вместе с [`CDPSession`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#class-cdpsession):

```js
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', { behavior: 'deny' });
```

Но учтите, что, судя по документации, `'Page.setDownloadBehavior'` одновременно  experimental и deprecated. К сожалению, других методов я не знаю, может, ещё кто-то подскажет.

P.S. Проверяем поведение (щелчок по ссылке игнорируется):

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null });

const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
      <a download href='data:text/plain,abc'>Download</a>
    </body>
  </html>`;

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
  await client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', { behavior: 'deny' });
} catch(err) { console.error(err); } finally { /* await browser.close(); */ }
```

Comment: мне кажется это не стабильный вариант, использовал исключение ссылки по расширению, но это не стабильный вариант также, появилась идея изменить папку для скачивания, а саму папку сделать в озу и не большую, если браузер не сможет записать файл, ну и ладно